# Download a file with PowerShell and Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, powershell, download, http-headers, attachment

I want to automate the download of my bills, so I started to write a PowerShell script for that. Mostly everything works fine: logging in at the page and navigating to the download page.

The problem is, that the download button doesn't link directly to the wanted PDF file but to a page which serves the file as an attachment in the HTTP headers instead, so I can't use `System.Net.WebClient` to download the file.

But the IE asks for confirmation to download the file. **So is there any chance to click on "save" in the confirmation window with PowerShell?**

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately not, I would take a different approach, and skip internet explorer. But, If you can obtain the url of the pdf (with [wireshark maybe](http://www.wireshark.org)), then try using system.net.webclient to download the file. All of what you stated should be able to be accomplished with powershell. You might have to get creative with passing your creds through when accessing the file, but depending on the technology your billing company uses it's probably doable. It's a stretch, but you may be able to just download the file directly using powershell.

You could also try to tell IE to automatically save files of this type, Not sure what version of IE you're using though.